# Executing find command with a file having directory lists

Tags: linux, awk, sed, find

I have a big file which contains directories paths like below:

```
$PRJ/fp/t/mxl/lf/
$PRJ/fp/t/mxl/lf/
```

I want to read this file line by line and list out all the files inside each directory file in a line in output file.

output file should look like below:

```
$PRJ/fp/t/mxl/lf/ring.lf
$PRJ/fp/t/mxl/lf/rin.lef
```

I can use find command with directory path specified but how to use it with a file having directory paths?
`find input_file -type f` does not work.

Can anybody suggest a way how to list files inside directories, directory paths are in a file which is given as input.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is already answered where the OP asked it on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/q/73206662/1745001. Please don't multi-post.

Answer (score 3):

GNU `find` can read the starting points iteratively from a file with the `-files0-from` option, which specifies a file containing `NUL`-delimited set of paths.  To process *only* those specified directories and not their children, you can also use `-maxdepth 0`. The `-files0-from` option is available in GNU `find` 4.9.0 (2022-02-22) or later.

In your case you need to convert (`tr`) the newline-separated list of files to a `NUL`-delimited list of files and then have `find` read that list as its set of input directories to scan. For example,

```
tr '\n' '\0' <input_file | find -maxdepth 0 -files0-from - -type d -print
```

Comment: The directory paths are there in an input file. how to use find command on a input file which has directory paths inside?

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY what do you mean? This is exactly what the answers shows you. Just replace `input_file` with the name of your file with directory paths.